# Since you can make the verb swap

Tags: meaning

*In Cyndi's sentence, you can replace “feel” with “am.” “I feel bad” becomes “I am bad.” **Since you can make the verb swap**, you know that “feel” is a linking verb in that sentence and is describing her state.*

Source: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/bad-versus-badly?page=1

I would like to ask about the part "make the verb swap" in the above sentence. I think that the meaning is the same as  "you can swap the verb" but the original phrase seems to me odd. I am familiar with a sentence "like Skydiving makes me excited" but this pattern does not work in my sentence. What does "make the verb swap" exactly mean?

Comment: *"Since you can make the swap, you know [blah blah]". "What kind of swap do you mean?" "The **verb** swap!"* I'd say "verb" there looks like a "noun adjunct" usage. And "make" here means ***perform***, not ***force, cause to become***.

Comment: Thank you. So "verb" is the adjective and "swap" in the noun. How simple…

Comment: That's how I'd "parse" it, yes. I suppose one could (perversely, imho) interpret *make the verb swap* as ***force** one of the verbs to **swap** places with the other verb*, but since by implication you'd also have to "force" the ***other*** verb to swap places as well, I'd expect ***verbs*** to be pluralised if that's what the speaker had in mind.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. It's more obvious in the paragraph next to your quote, i.e., *Since you can't make the swap, you know that “feel” is an action verb in that sentence; it's describing an action.*

Comment: @Damkerng T.: Excellent point! I admit I didn't actually follow the link to the source. But as you say, the fact that *Since you can* is followed just two sentences later by *Since you can't* is a ***very*** strong indicator of parallel constructions. And since the "adjectival" element ***verb*** isn't repeated in the second instance it should be reasonably obvious that in both cases the operative noun is ***swap***. Reasonably obvious to a native speaker, I mean - such things are presumably much harder to spot if you're struggling a bit because it's all in a foreign language.